# Laravel One to Many relation with 2 primary keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship, eager-loading

I've 2 tables

1. Users table

```
    id
    name
    ...
```

2. Chats table

```
    id
    from_id // fk - id on users, the user sent the message
    to_id   // fk - id on users, intended user
    message_body
```

Now, I'm trying to set up One to Many relation where user has many chat messages but a chat message has two user. **from** and **to** user

How can I define this relationship?. I have to user eager loading.

I tried to use [Compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships) but it didn't work.
My code

User Model

```
public function chats() {
    return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, ['from_id', 'to_id'], 'id');
}
```

Chat Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, ['from_id', 'to_id'], 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like that?

On your User model, set up two relationships like this:

```
public function chatsFrom() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chat', 'from_id');
}

public function chatsTo() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chat', 'to_id');
}
```

Then, on your Chat model, also set up two relationships, one to `from` and another to `to`, both referencing a User model. Like this:

```
public function fromUser() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from_id');
}

public function toUser() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'to_id');
}
```

This way, you can access the relationships using something like this:

```
$user->chatsFrom();
$user->chatsTo();

$chat->fromUser();
$chat->toUser();
```

Comment: I thought about it but I want to do things like `$user->chats()->delete();` this.

Comment: @APu but if you have different users on `from` and `to` on a single chat you cannot do that. Unless you are willing to delete posts which have different users.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function chats() {
  return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, 'from_id', 'id') + $this->hasMany(Chat::class,'to_id','id');
}

public function userFrom() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from_id', 'id');
}

public function userTo() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Please try to through few chars to make others understand what you did & how this works